# VSHost.exe keeps starting in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm working in VS2010 with a solution with lots of projects and it is constantly becoming unresponsive.

One thing I've noticed which may be a clue is that MyApplicationName.vshost.exe is constantly popping up in the process list despite the fact that I have not started any debugging. It could be happening whenever a build takes place perhaps?

I'm not launching the application from within VS at all. I'm just executing it from within the bin directory.

Killing the vshost.exe process seems to often cause VS2010 to become responsive again.

Any ideas why this process could keep getting spawned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your project properties, try unchecking the following box in the Debug tab:

- Enable the Visual Studio hosting process

Comment: You have just saved me throwing my monitor out the window.. My boss thanks you !